# FFmpeg : Slow seeking on compression process

Tags: ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg to cut some parts of videos. To target the part I want, I usually use the options `-ss 01:00:00 -to 01:00:10`. That allow me to select the 10 seconds I want to grab but more far the start point is, more time it takes for ffmpeg to start to work because of seeking. I could use that `-ss` option before `-i` to instant seeking, but now the timestamp is reseted to zero and, the `-to` option works like a `-t`. This behaviour needs to calculate the end point instead of just write it.

Is there any possibility to combine instant seeking with the option `-to` ?

Answer (score 1):

So you may want to include your raw command line but I can give you a few pointers.

Using `-ss` after the `-i` is going to need to decode that amount before it gets to where you want to start processing from. If there is a time delay then this is the likely cause.

You could do something along these lines:

> -ss 00:59:00.000 -i input -ss 00:01:00.000

This means goes to about 59 minutes in then start decoding a minute forward before processing.

If you want to keep initial time offsets I would experiment with.

> -itsoffset -copytb -copyts

I do not know for certain which will do the trick for you as the original command-line is not given but I hope this moves you closer to your goal.

There are several articles that talk about this topic but here is one that I'll sometimes use for reference.

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking%20with%20FFmpeg

Comment: Thank you but I already tested the first example `-ss -i -ss -to`, it doesn't work. I gonna check with `-itsoffset` `-copytb` `-copyts`.